# How to get data back from UI - grid after applying filter operation?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

I am using Angular Js in my project. To display data and perform search or filter operation, I am using UI-grid. I need the filtered data back to generate a chart and other functionalities. I want to extract only result data or visible data from grid view. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer.

```
var visibledata =scope.gridApi.core.getVisibleRows(scope.gridApi.grid);

var selecteddata = scope.gridApi.selection.getSelectedRows();
```

And put below code in gridoption.

```
onRegisterApi: function(gridApi){
     scope.gridApi = gridApi;
}
```